# Distribute the cost of a resource among users, considering concurrent use

Tags: google-bigquery

## The problem

I have the following scenario: a given resource, available for a determined period of time, costs a fixed amount of money during that time. And I have users which can access that resource during that time. I need to distribute the cost of the resources among the users who accessed it, considering that an user can't be charged for the period when he wasn't accessing it. Something like this:

[image: example 1]

The red bar represents the availability of the resource across the time. The blue and green bars represent the time when the respective users were accessing the resource. Note that at the time 9, no one is accessing the resource, so no one is charged. Considering that the resource cost `$ 100` during the entire time, User 1 would be charged for `$ 40` and User 2 `$ 50`. `$ 10` would be lost.

The idea is for that case is simple: take the full cost of the resource and divide by the time used by each user. But the problem rises when we have concurrent usage of the resource:

[image: example 2]

In this case, at time 4 and 5, both users are using the same resource. In this case, I need to divide the cost of the overlapping times by 2 (the number of the concurrent users), giving me the right values.

In other words: the more users I have using the resource, the cheaper it becomes for each user.

Of course the problem can become even more complicated, like this:

[image: example 3]

## The data

Currently I have a table with the following structure (using the example 3):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ResourceId |UserId |UsageStart |UsageEnd |ResourceTotalCost |WeightedCost |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|res1       |u1     |time 0     |time 1   |100               |20           |
|res1       |u1     |time 4     |time 7   |100               |40           |
|res1       |u2     |time 4     |time 8   |100               |50           |
|res1       |u3     |time 1     |time 4   |100               |40           |
|res1       |u3     |time 8     |time 8   |100               |10           |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the exact period of the usage of each user, joined with the total cost of the resource (of the entire period of analysis), and the weighted cost of the resource by the user (which is the column I want to improve).

`UsageStart` and `UsageEnd` columns are timestamps, and have millisecond precision (which means that times can be 1ms apart from each other). `ResourceId` and `UserId` are strings with no pattern (but guaranteed to be unique for each resource and user, respectively). `ResourceTotalCost` and `WeightedCost` are both float numbers.

## The output

The output I need is the same one I'm already having, but with the weighted cost considering the concurrent usage of the resource among the users. For the example 3, this is the expected output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ResourceId |UserId |UsageStart |UsageEnd |ResourceTotalCost |WeightedCost |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|res1       |u1     |time 0     |time 1   |100               |15           |
|res1       |u1     |time 4     |time 7   |100               |18.33        |
|res1       |u2     |time 4     |time 8   |100               |23.33        |
|res1       |u3     |time 1     |time 4   |100               |28.33        |
|res1       |u3     |time 8     |time 8   |100               |5            |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, any ideas on how to solve this problem? I considered using [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) to solve that, but currently the usage of UDF imposes several restrictions (such as 6 UDF queries at the same time) that I can't afford on my project, so pure BigQuery SQL is preferable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below - it is for BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql))

As you see - I slightly adjust your data (UsageStart and UsageEnd are integers)
I involved all three your examples respectively marked as res1, res2 and res3 for ResourceId
Also I added extra entry for each resource to have resource availability presented. Those entries have UserId is NULL

So the query is

```
WITH Usage AS (
  SELECT ResourceId, UserId, UsageStart, UsageEnd + 1 AS UsageEnd, ResourceTotalCost 
  FROM (SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 1 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, 4 AS UsageStart, 7 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, 4 AS UsageStart, 8 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u3' AS UserId, 1 AS UsageStart, 4 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u3' AS UserId, 8 AS UsageStart, 8 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 9 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 3 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, 4 AS UsageStart, 8 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 9 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 5 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, 4 AS UsageStart, 8 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, 0 AS UsageStart, 9 AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost )
), iIntervals AS (
  SELECT ResourceId, iStart, LEAD(iStart) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ResourceId ORDER BY iStart) AS iEnd
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ResourceId, iStart FROM (
      SELECT ResourceId, UsageStart AS iStart FROM Usage UNION ALL 
      SELECT ResourceId, UsageEnd AS iStart FROM Usage )
  )
), iWeights AS (
  SELECT iStart, iEnd, x.ResourceId, UserId, ResourceTotalCost, 
    SUM(iWeight / CASE WHEN Users = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Users END / width) AS iWeight
  FROM (
    SELECT iStart, iEnd, iEnd - iStart AS iWeight, iIntervals.ResourceId, UserId, ResourceTotalCost, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) OVER(PARTITION BY iIntervals.ResourceId, iStart, iEnd) AS Users 
    FROM iIntervals JOIN Usage
    ON iIntervals.ResourceId = Usage.ResourceId
    AND iStart >= UsageStart AND iEnd <= UsageEnd 
    WHERE iEnd IS NOT NULL ) AS x
  JOIN (SELECT ResourceId, MAX(iEnd) - MIN(iStart) AS width FROM iIntervals GROUP BY 1) AS y
  ON x.ResourceId = y.ResourceId WHERE NOT (UserId IS NULL AND Users > 0) GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
)
SELECT usage.ResourceId, usage.UserId, usage.UsageStart, usage.UsageEnd - 1 as UsageEnd, 
  iWeights.ResourceTotalCost, ROUND(SUM(iWeights.ResourceTotalCost * iWeight), 2) AS WeightedCost 
FROM Usage JOIN iWeights 
ON usage.ResourceId = iWeights.ResourceId AND usage.UserId = iWeights.UserId
AND iWeights.iStart BETWEEN usage.UsageStart AND usage.UsageEnd
AND iWeights.iEnd BETWEEN usage.UsageStart AND usage.UsageEnd
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

with below  output, which is what is expected I think

```
ResourceId  UserId  UsageStart  UsageEnd    ResourceTotalCost   WeightedCost     
res1            u1           0         3                100          40.0    
res1            u2           4         8                100          50.0    
res2            u1           0         5                100          50.0    
res2            u2           4         8                100          40.0    
res3            u1           0         1                100          15.0    
res3            u1           4         7                100          18.33   
res3            u2           4         8                100          23.33   
res3            u3           1         4                100          28.33   
res3            u3           8         8                100           5.0
```

Most likely your UsageStart and UsageEnd are not integers, so you will need to adjust above solution respectively. But my focus was on giving you solid example of logic to process with.

Hope this helped! And it might potentially be optimized too

Comment: I'll adjust the question to better explain the data types. The UsageStart and UsageEnd are, in fact, timestamps.

Comment: can you just stick with your original question and just check and confirm if it is doing what you expected? you might be then able to modify code to use timestamps instead of integers. but at least would be great to know if this does work for you!

Comment: Your answer works like a charm. I apologize for not saying where the billing start and end date comes from (you assumed there are some NULLs in the table, but in the real model they come from another 2 columns). Do you want me to update the question with those columns or accept it the way it is?

Comment: No :o) - i haven't assumed - i just added this these extra rows as it was required for me to go ahead and help you with having some working code. Next time  - please be accurate and more detailed in formulating/presenting your question(s) - so I (or someone else) am not doing something and then realizing that it is not what you needed me to help you with. Usually such "exercises" are quite time- and efforts- consuming and it is a little frustrating to end up this way :o( Anyway - i will try to help you more and modify code  - but, again  - please check your question again and make sure its Ok

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for that. Creating such specific questions is an exercise by itself too, and sometimes some important details can slip away. I won't change the question and accept your answer as it is. Thanks for your hard work and for the time you spent on it.

Comment: yes, agree  - it is a challenge - and i see your questions are usually well spelled - I already helped you few times :o) and i really like the way you ask and present your questions. but shit happens  - no problem! i still will try to set a time and adjust the answer. will post when done

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me from answering this using MySQL procedures and not BitQuery functions, but it should be useful.
I had to make some assumptions from your model:

- The resource1 in question is used on all timeslots, in your example, 10 timeslots ($10 per time), even though your data only uses 9
- It is reasonable to assume you can afford a O(n) query on all possible timeslots
- Your `UsageTable` has an `ID` primary key column

You can do a loop by using 1 select and 1 update queries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `calculateUsage`()
BEGIN

set @slot = 0;
repeat
set @increase = 
(
select slotcost/count(id) as usercost
from (
select id, ResourceTotalCost/10 as slotcost
from UsageTable
where @slot between UsageStart and UsageEnd
) as x
);

update UsageTable
set WeightedCost = WeightedCost + @increase
where @slot between UsageStart and UsageEnd;

set @slot = @slot + 1;
until @slot = 10 end repeat;

END
```

Running that query updated the table as:

```
ID  RID UID St  End RTC     WC
1   1   1   0   1   100.00  15.00
2   1   1   4   7   100.00  18.33
3   1   2   4   8   100.00  23.33
4   1   3   1   4   100.00  28.33
5   1   3   8   8   100.00  5.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. On BigQuery, such procedures cloud be written using UDF, which imposes several limitations to your query execution, so I prefer not to use them (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer for adjusted/corrected question

```
UsageStart and UsageEnd columns are timestamps, and have millisecond precision (which means that times can be 1ms apart from each other).   
ResourceId and UserId are strings with no pattern (but guaranteed to be unique for each resource and user, respectively).   
ResourceTotalCost and WeightedCost are both float numbers.
```

I didn't want to ruin my previous answer because it is still correct (and covers scenarios with discrete intervals for example and similar) so someone still hopefully will find it very useful as is

So, now - the new query is (still BigQuery Standard SQL of course)

```
WITH Usage AS (
  SELECT ResourceId, UserId, UsageStart, UsageEnd AS UsageEnd, ResourceTotalCost 
  FROM (
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:02.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:04.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:08.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:04.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:09.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u3' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:01.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:05.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, 'u3' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:08.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:09.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res3' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:10.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:04.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:04.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:09.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res1' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:10.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, 'u1' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:06.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, 'u2' AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:04.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:09.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost UNION ALL
    SELECT 'res2' AS ResourceId, NULL AS UserId, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000' AS UsageStart, TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 01:00:10.000' AS UsageEnd, 100 AS ResourceTotalCost )
), iIntervals AS (
  SELECT ResourceId, iStart, LEAD(iStart) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ResourceId ORDER BY iStart) AS iEnd
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ResourceId, iStart FROM (
      SELECT ResourceId, UsageStart AS iStart FROM Usage UNION ALL 
      SELECT ResourceId, UsageEnd AS iStart FROM Usage )
  )
), iWeights AS (
  SELECT iStart, iEnd, x.ResourceId, UserId, ResourceTotalCost, 
    SUM(iWeight / CASE WHEN Users = 0 THEN 1 ELSE Users END / width) AS iWeight
  FROM (
    SELECT iStart, iEnd, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(iEnd, iStart, MILLISECOND) AS iWeight, iIntervals.ResourceId, UserId, ResourceTotalCost, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT UserId) OVER(PARTITION BY iIntervals.ResourceId, iStart, iEnd) AS Users 
    FROM iIntervals JOIN Usage
    ON iIntervals.ResourceId = Usage.ResourceId
    AND iStart >= UsageStart AND iEnd <= UsageEnd 
    WHERE iEnd IS NOT NULL ) AS x
  JOIN (SELECT ResourceId, MAX(UNIX_MILLIS(iEnd)) - MIN(UNIX_MILLIS(iStart)) AS width FROM iIntervals GROUP BY 1) AS y
  ON x.ResourceId = y.ResourceId WHERE NOT (UserId IS NULL AND Users > 0) GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
)
SELECT usage.ResourceId, usage.UserId, usage.UsageStart, usage.UsageEnd as UsageEnd, 
  iWeights.ResourceTotalCost, ROUND(SUM(iWeights.ResourceTotalCost * iWeight), 2) AS WeightedCost 
FROM Usage JOIN iWeights 
ON usage.ResourceId = iWeights.ResourceId AND usage.UserId = iWeights.UserId
AND iWeights.iStart BETWEEN usage.UsageStart AND usage.UsageEnd
AND iWeights.iEnd BETWEEN usage.UsageStart AND usage.UsageEnd
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

the output is similar to one in previous example as intervals are the same (even though now presented with Start and End as TIMESTAMPs)

```
ResourceId UserId UsageStart                 UsageEnd         ResourceTotalCost WeightedCost     
      res1    u1  2016-01-01 01:00:00 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:04 UTC         100.0    40.0     
      res1    u2  2016-01-01 01:00:04 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:09 UTC         100.0    50.0     
      res2    u1  2016-01-01 01:00:00 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:06 UTC         100.0    50.0     
      res2    u2  2016-01-01 01:00:04 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:09 UTC         100.0    40.0     
      res3    u1  2016-01-01 01:00:00 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:02 UTC         100.0    15.0     
      res3    u1  2016-01-01 01:00:04 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:08 UTC         100.0    18.33    
      res3    u2  2016-01-01 01:00:04 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:09 UTC         100.0    23.33    
      res3    u3  2016-01-01 01:00:01 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:05 UTC         100.0    28.33    
      res3    u3  2016-01-01 01:00:08 UTC  2016-01-01 01:00:09 UTC         100.0     5.0
```